# $6$ points in the interior of a square of side length $2$.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Prove that having $6$ points in the interior of a square of side length $2$, we can choose $3$ of them so that the sum of distance between them is less than $3\sqrt{2}$. Is there a simple way?

Comment: sum of the disyances?

Comment: @Soke yes that is sum

Comment: To make the claim in geometrical terms - given 6 points on a square there is always a triangle created by 3 of the points with a perimeter less than 1 and 1/2 of the diagonal. Is this interpretation right?

Comment: I suggest dividing the square into four squares of unit length.  If three of more points lie in the same unit square, the result is not hard to prove.  The more difficult case occurs when none of the unit squares contains more than two of the points.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to prove this, because the statement is false!

Place four points at the corners of the square, and two points at $(x,x)$ and $(2-x,2-x)$, where $x\approx 0.48735$ (though any $x\in[0.44,0.5)$ works).

[image]

Then the minimum perimeter of any triangle in the configuration is

$$\frac{6+5\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{22-4\sqrt{2}}}{4}\approx4.2784\ldots\approx3\sqrt{2}+0.03578$$

attained by both the triangles consisting of two adjacent corners and the nearest interior point, and the smaller of the two degenerate triangles lying on the diagonal.

(Because this configuration has all triangles with a strictly larger perimeter, we can move any of the points around by epsilon if we wish to e.g. avoid degenerate triangles, or have all points lie in the interior of the square.)